# knockout + jqueryui autocomplete bug in IE8

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, knockout.js, internet-explorer-8

I have this situation. A jquery autocomplete with knockoutjs, which works fine on all browers, except IE8. When we select an item in autocomplete list, the normal behavior is close the list, after we click (select) a list item.

But, in IE8 the list still openned. I have already done almost everything to hack this bug, but without success. Our client is a company which has IE8 installed in all PCs, and we need to adapt this function to works on IE8.

Below, I put some code to illustrate the problem:

HTML:

```
        <div class="lado-a-lado-linear" data-bind="visible: parametros().usaCentroDeCusto || plano().centroDeCusto()">
            <label>Centro de Custo <span class="requerido" data-bind="visible: parametros().centroDeCustoObrigatorio">*</span></label>
            <input type="text" data-bind="value: (plano().centroDeCusto() || {}).nome, autocomplete: { source: onRequestCentroDeCusto, minLength: 0, select: onSelectCentroDeCusto, change: onChangeCentroDeCusto, scroll: onScrollCentroDeCusto, requestOnFocus: true }, validationElement: plano().centroDeCusto, enable: editaDadosPlano" />
        </div>
```

Knockout extension for autocomplete:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.autocomplete = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        var options = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
    $(element).autocomplete(options);

    ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(element, function () {
        $(element).autocomplete("destroy");
    });

    if (options.requestOnFocus)
        $(element).focus(function(){
            if ($(element).autocomplete("widget").is(":visible")) 
                return;
            $(element).data("uiAutocomplete").search($(this).val());
        });

    if (options.multipleSelection) {
        $(element).parent().click(function () { Expense.mainViewModel.resizeAutocomplete($(element).parent()); });
        $(element).blur(function () { $(element).width(0); });
    }

    if (options.scroll)
        $(element).autocomplete("widget").scroll(function () {
            if ($(this).scrollTop() + $(this).innerHeight() >= $(this)[0].scrollHeight)
                options.scroll(element);
        });

    $(element).bind('keydown', function (event) {
        var viewModel = Expense.mainViewModel || Expense.loginViewModel;
        return viewModel.onKeyDownAutocomplete(event, options.change);
    });
},
update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
    var options = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
    $(element).autocomplete("option", options);
}
```

};

Knockout viewmodel:

```
self.centrosDeCusto = []
self.onRequestCentroDeCusto = function (request, response) {
    var append = request.term.indexOf('{append}') > -1;
    var skip = append ? '&$skip=' + self.centrosDeCusto.length.toString() : '';
    var terms = '?$top=30&select=id,nome&nome=' + request.term.replace('{append}', '') + skip;
    var url = self.resolveUrl('usuarios/' + self.plano().favorecido().id + '/centrosdecusto/' + terms);

    self.ajaxRequest('GET', url)
        .done(function (data) {
            if (append)
                self.centrosDeCusto = self.centrosDeCusto.concat(data);
            else
                self.centrosDeCusto = data;

            response($.map(self.centrosDeCusto, function (item) {
                return {
                    label: item.nome,
                    value: item.nome,
                    data: item
                }
            }));
        });
};

self.onScrollCentroDeCusto = function (element) {
    if (self.centrosDeCusto.length < 30 || self.centrosDeCusto.length % 30 == 0)
        $(element).autocomplete("search", $(element).val() + '{append}');
};

self.onSelectCentroDeCusto = function (event, ui) {
    self.plano().centroDeCusto(ui.item.data);
};

self.onChangeCentroDeCusto = function (event, ui) {
    ui = ui || {}; 

    if ($(event.currentTarget).val() == '')
        self.plano().centroDeCusto(null);
    else if (!ui.item && self.centrosDeCusto.length == 1)
        self.plano().centroDeCusto(self.centrosDeCusto[0]);
    else if (self.plano().centroDeCusto() && self.plano().centroDeCusto().nome == $(event.currentTarget).val()) {
    }
    else if (!ui.item && $(event.currentTarget).val() != '') {
        self.plano().centroDeCusto(null);
        setTimeout(function () { alert("É necessário selecionar um Centro de Custo da lista"); }, 0);
        $(event.currentTarget).focus();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
};
```

So, I need to implement the same behavior we have in all browsers, which is : after we write the search words, autocomplete fires and a list with items appears. Then we select one of this items and the list disappears/closes.

Only in IE8, this list continues oppened, showing the selected item I have choosen, just below the input field. This list only closes when I blur the field. But, everytime I click the input field, the list is showed again.

I don't know if the problem is with knockoutjs or jquery ui, or both.

I have already tried with the versions below without success. It could be a combination of some versions ?!?!

- jquery 1.11.0 + jquery-ui-1.10.2 + knockout 3.0.0
- jquery 1.9.1  + jquery-ui-1.10.2 + knockout 3.0.0

Best regards,
Marcelo.

Comment: There are no errors being thrown at at all?

Comment: No, no errors !!! You can see this behavior using IE 10 or 11 with dev tools (F12) and configuring to IE8.

Comment: Another information... this behavior is just with mouse click. If I use keyboard with arrows and tab keys, the list closes ok. But, if I choose an item with mouse, the item still remains showing in the list just below input field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To everyone that needs to resolve a bug similiar with that, I have already resolved this bug, and I am putting here the solution.

The problem was in a extension made by my company, which was using the focus() event associated with jquery autocomplete. Below I show the original event source code:

```
$(element).focus(function(){
   if ($(element).autocomplete("widget").is(":visible")) 
       return;
   $(element).data("uiAutocomplete").search($(this).val());
});
```

Below it the new source code, where I changed focus() to focusin() and focusout():

```
 $(element).focusin(function () {
   if ($(element).val().length == 0) {
       if ($(element).autocomplete("widget").is(":visible"))
          return;
       $(element).data("uiAutocomplete").search($(this).val());
   }
 });
 $(element).focusout(function () {
   if ($(element).autocomplete("widget").is(":hidden"))
       return;
 });
```

With that, I could resolve the IE8 bug.